# ISAM error in SQL for the data been present is faced

Tags: sql

In SQL ,

> `ISAMFileManager` `executeQuery` file not found (from Date,toDate)

error is been faced.

Comment: Show the full query you are running and the full error message you are receiving.

Comment: Make sure to add what you have tried so far and what went wrong. Also try to include output and/or errors so we can better help you. Remember, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but there are a lot of helpful people here that are willing to take a look if you make an effort to explain your problem.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This is coming as front end error as ( ISAMFileManager executeQuery:(file) not found for (from Date, to Date) ) where inputs are the date range as in the database which is valid using Microsoft SQL Server management Studio.

Comment: what front end is that, then? What language? Where's your code? We have no idea what the context is.